# Unable to understand .NAVI extension file in android project

Tags: android

why we use .NAVI file in android.some developer add this file into project.please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no files named `.navi` in normal Android projects. If you have a `.navi` file in your project, please ask whoever gave you the project why they put a `.navi` file in the project.

Comment: they put .NAVI file in assets folder.i dont no why but i hope they use some navigation in there tiles based custom floor plan project.

Comment: @user1527136: You can put anything you want in `assets/`, but then it is up to you to have code that can do something with the data.

Comment: they use .navi file for navigation on custom floor plan.they pasre .navi file using some parse.